# Is it possible to use embedded php to echo an attribute name?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

```
<input value='Like' id='?><?php echo htmlspecialchars(htmlentities($get_id)); ?><?php' type='button'    class='blog-link2'></input>
```

I tried to use JQuery to use the id field to trigger a change in the input tag but it doesn't work. Can somebody please tell me where I am going wrong?

Comment: input doesn't require closing tag it should be `<input value="" />`

Comment: it has a closing tag..or u can rewrite the code for me if u can?

Comment: input dont have closing tag and why a question mark after id as <input value='like' id=' ?>

Answer (score 0):

You are adding another `<?php` tag.
Try this:

```
<input value='Like' id='<?php echo htmlspecialchars(htmlentities($get_id)); ?>' type='button'    class='blog-link2'>
```